# Enabling IPV4 is not working

Tags: macos, ipv6, hostname, jdk1.7

I have a java program to get the host name and it is failing to get the host name in Java 1.7_79 version in MAC OS.

I know that putting the host name in the /etc/hosts or disabling IPV6 (use only IPV4)

But I wanted to enable/disable IPV6 through java program. When I execute the java program by passing the parameter (java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  GetHostName) getting unknown host name.

What is the best way to pass this parameter in the Java program? Are there any other ways to get the host name in Java 1.7 (1.7.79) in Mac OS?

Thank you.

Comment: What if the host for which you are requesting the name doesn't have a DNS A record, only an AAAA record? Getting an unknow host seems to indicate that there is a problem with DNS.

Comment: I read lot of articles around this problem. Most of them complained about Java 1.7 version. With the Java 1.8 version, it works for me.